# How can I kill PID automatically after using 'fork:= true' in build.sbt in scala?

Tags: python, scala, sbt, fork

I'm using scalapy to integrate python code into scala (intellij idea). For this I've to include some setting in build.sbt.

**build.sbt:**

```
import ai.kien.python.Python

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "my-project"
  )

ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

version in Docker:= "0.0.3"
dockerExposedPorts:= Seq(8083)

fork:= true

lazy val python = Python("/usr/bin/python3")

lazy val javaOpts = python.scalapyProperties.get.map {
  case (k, v) => s"""-D$k=$v"""
}.toSeq

javaOptions ++= javaOpts

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "me.shadaj" %% "scalapy-core" % "0.5.2"
)
```

Here we have to set **fork** equals to **true** which we have seen from the documentation of **shadaj library**.

Now the problem is each time when I run my main class - it creates a new child/process and run that main class. For example if run first time it will run main class with 8083 port (akka-http). Then when I run again it gives 8083 is already in use, even if I close the program or even close intellij idea it gives same thing (port already used) on running main class.

Now what I want to do is when I run main class it do fork and run on other process but after completing task it kill that process automatically.

What I do manually is:

```
I have checked process using terminal command:

    pgrep -a java

and I killed forked processes using terminal command:

    kill -9 {pid}
```

What is the solution of this to do automatically?

Comment: Which SBT version is your project using? And which one do you have locally? Look's like a [similar bug](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/6738) has been solved in 1.6.x.

Comment: @GaëlJ I'm using sbt version 1.2.8 and scala version 2.13.1.

Comment: Then I suggest you try with latest SBT version. In the build.sbt should be enough but if it still doesn't work try by upgrading the binary (CLI) as well.